# Prior to Windows 7, did windows not have any ability to group themselves in the Taskbar in this manner?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, windows-98

Since even Windows 7 is now long since EOL, this is not a practical question of a problem I'm facing. Rather, I'm curious whether or not I would've been able to run my system back in those days of Windows XP, Windows 2000, Windows 98 and earlier.

Basically, I constantly have a large number of cmd.exe windows running. Actually, it's PHP.exe, but it looks like/uses cmd.exe "wrapped around it", kinda. It's hard to explain and I don't fully understand it myself. The point is that I have a lot of cmd.exe processes/windows running at all times, and new ones are spawned all the time as others finish (and thus disappear).

Basically, I simulate "threads" or "doing many things at once" by having them all run their own separate php.exe instance (which in practice means cmd.exe instances).

This works flawlessly on my Windows 10, and the same in Windows 8, and Windows 7 (unless I misremember). However, I'm foggy on Windows Vista, Windows XP and earlier. I'm not sure that they "grouped" taskbar icons like Windows does now.

If those earlier versions of Windows did not, which I suspect and seem to remember, does that mean that I would constantly get a big ugly mess of "minimized window bars" in the Taskbar, appearing and disappearing and making my "actual" applications hard to use/switch between as a result, and of course the visual pollution/annoyance of having things appear and disappear/rearrange in the Taskbar all the time?

If such was the case, would there have been any built-in/reasonable way to "mitigate" this? Or would I essentially not have been able to run my PHP CLI-based system on Windows Vista and earlier? (In sane/clean manner, without going crazy.)

Even on Windows 10, I have had to use this third-party "Winaero Tweaker" application to disable the Taskbar thumbnails and instead get a nice list of processes, so even on Windows 10, there was minor tweaking necessary. (Well, not strictly *necessary*, but those thumbnail icons that Windows 10 uses when there's few enough processes in a given Taskbar group were very annoying when I tried to get a quick overview of what is open/currently running.)

I have no copy of Windows XP/Vista/98 left to install this in a VM and try it out myself, sadly.

I am fully able to use my Windows 10 desktop and never notice my system other than seeing that there is a cmd.exe Taskbar group right there, which I can click once to get a list of what exactly is running. This is what I'm trying to determine if older versions of Windows used to be able to do. (Or something which would work equally well and pleasantly and without problems as I use other applications and the Tasbar.)

Comment: This question cannot be answered authoritatively because OP has noted they don't have the ability to even run an XP VM to test any proposed solutions. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm curious whether or not I would've been able to run my system back
> in those days of Windows XP, Windows 2000, Windows 98 and earlier.

I do not know what do you mean by System here. If you are referring to some programs or whatever you are testing now, then depending upon what dependencies are used if any and how they existed in XP if any, it may or may not run on XP.

If you purely want to know if XP had the ability to group similar tasks in the taskbar then Yes. It did have. However, in addition to checking the required option in Taskbar properties, you as well needed a DWORD Valued named `TaskbarGroupSize` at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```

In the registry.
Set this value to 2 and any two or more similar instances of program would get grouped on the taskbar.

See a snapshot from my XP Pro SP3 running in a Vmware VM. Note that this is not extensively tested with several other apps. Just ran 2 -3 instances of CMD.exe that's it. Also this is just to fulfil your curiosity. As such you don't seem to be ever going to use Windows XP.

[image]

Since this is not a practical problem or issue that you are actually facing, this question might as well get considered as out of scope on this site!

Answer (score -3):

From what I can remember, the grouping of programs on the taskbar started with Windows 7.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1002055)

Comment: It does answer the question. He wants to know if windows versions prior to windows 7 grouped the same program on the taskbar.

Comment: The phrasing makes it based on memory, not fact, and patkim's answer above indicates your memory is incorrect. Even if it was incorrect, having a clearer statement, rather than a surmise, would have made this a better answer and not likely to be removed.

Comment: Patkim's answer describes a registry tweak. The average user will have zero knowledge of registry tweaks as they are not accessible via control panel, properties or any standard window graphical interface.

Comment: Now you're making assumptions about OP and readers in order to justify an incorrect answer. An individuals supposed inability to perform certain actions does not mean we don't give them a correct answer.